# evaluate string containing expression in the form of number X number

Tags: python

I have a table represented as a text table. See below:

```
| foo foo foo            |          | 20M   | 20M            |          17M | 19M |
| foo                  | foo12345  | 10M   | 5M           |           5M | 5M |
| foo.foo                   | foo12345  | 4x10M | 4x10M          |           0M | 1M |
| foo                    | foo12345  | 10M   | 5M           |           0M | 0M |
| foo foo                 | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 0M |
| foo foo foo          | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |            0M |  0M |
| foo                   | foo12345  | 2x10M | 2x10M          |           5M | 5M |
| foo foo              | foo12345 | 10M   | 5M           |            0M |  0M |
| foo                     | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           2M |  3M |
| foo foo                  | foo12345 | 10M   | 5M           |           3M | 4M |
| foo                         | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 0M |
| foo                     | foo12345  | 2x10M | 2x10M          |           7M | 8M |
| foo foo                 | foo12345 | 10M   | 5M           |           1M | 1M |
| foo                        | foo12345   | 10M   | 10M            |           1M | 1M |
| foo                         | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |            0M |  0M |
| foo foo 1                |          | 2M    | 2M             |           1M | 1M |
| foo foo 2                |          | 2M    | 2M             |           1M | 1M |
| foo                    | foo12345 | 10M   | 5M           |           2M | 2M |
| foo foo                  | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 1M |
| foo                    | foo12345  | 10M   | 1M             |           0M | 0M |
| foo                          | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 0M |
| foo foo    | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |           9M | 9M |
| foo                     | foo12345 | 10M   | 2M           |           1M | 1M |
| foo foo              |          | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 1M |
| foo                      | foo12345   | 10M   | 4M/4M        |           2M | 2M |
| foo                        | foo12345 | 1M    | 1M             |           0M | 0M |
| foo                       | foo12345  | 1M    | 1M             |            0M | 0M |
| foo                       | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 0M |
| foo                         | foo12345  | 2x10M | 2x10M          |            1M | 1M |
| foo                   | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |           9M | 9M |
| foo                     | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           5M | 5M |
| foo                   |          | 10M   | 10M            |           4M | 4M |
| foo                      | foo12345   | 10M   | 10M            |           0M |  0M |
| foo foo               | foo12345 | 10M   | 10M            |           0M | 0M |
| foo foo foo | foo12345 | 1M    | 1M             |           0M | 0M |
| foo                  | foo12345  | 2x1M  | 2x1M           |           1M | 1M |
| foo                     | foo12345  | 10M   | 10M            |           3M | 4M |
```

I want to transform it into a pandas df. I am able to do that except that I am left with some elements that contain a pattern like [number]X[number] example, 4x10M or 2X10M above.

Is there a way in python to evaluate this so in this example it will be 200? I have tried eval() but multiplication has to be expressed in "*".

What I have is a regex code like:

```py
#y contains the text above
y = re.sub('(\d+)(x\d{1})(\d?)(M)','\g<1>\g<3>M',y)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Also, this is a pretty common use case where you are presented with a text table. I am someone has created a script to transform text tables like this into a pandas dataframe. That would also be nice because if you see how crass my line of code, you haven't seen the rest :)

Thanks and pls excuse the original vague post.

Comment: As you noticed, multiplication is done via `*` in Python so `eval`uating the string will not help. Sounds like you will need to manually parse it. Maybe with regex...

Comment: You can replace the `X` with `*` using `my_string.replace('X', '*')`. This just if you don't have some limitation on doing this.

Comment: It's hard to help without more context. Please provide some example inputs and their expected outputs. Is it only numbers or `numberXnumber`? Can it be `+`? Can there be spaces? Is it from user input? A file? Try to be more specific and make this into an answerable question

Answer (score 1):

Without `eval` or regular expressions:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

s = "20X10"

res = reduce(mul, map(int, s.split("X")))
```

If you have to find such patterns within a longer string, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"(\d+)[xX](\d+)")

s = "abc20X10def"
res = reduce(mul, map(int, pat.search(s).groups()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) and [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) - but note that `eval` is not considered safe:

```
import re
s = '20X10'
s = re.sub(r'[xX]', '*', s)

print(eval(s))
# 200
```

Note that [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) does not work for this purpose in recent Python versions:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(s))
# ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x10a7141c0>
```